# Split Mysql Table internally

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, partitioning, mysqli

How to split the huge mysql table (size around 200GB) internally?
Is there any mechanism other than partition?
The table size is daily growing. Table created using innodb with indices.
Thanks in advance.

Table have around 30 columns. Most of the time, i use select * as i need to show all the field. Then there is no problem in fetching data. Problem is size of table. ibd file size is now around 200gb. There are many tables like this. So i need to split the table internally as i don't have access to modify the code.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://mysqlstepbystep.com/2015/04/03/spider-for-mysql-overview/).

Comment: @Vérace, thanks for the link. but this is related with mysql products. Is there any mechanism without using additional resources?

Comment: There are too many unknowns to give "one-size-fits-all" advice.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the important `SELECTs`.

Comment: Also, do you ever `DELETE` or `UPDATE` rows after they are inserted?

Comment: Table have around 30 columns. Most of the time, i use select * as i need to show all the field. Then there is no problem in fetching data. Problem is size of table. ibd file size is now around 200gb. There are many tables like this. So i need to split the table internally as i don't have access to modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is few ways to do it as per below-

1) partitioning but you don't want it. Also need to remember that partitioning does not support with foreign keys.

2) You can normalize your table if there is duplicate values in table.

3) If this table contains transactional data or logs then you can move old data in historical tables year wise etc if possible in your environment.

Comment: zafar. thanks. Normalization already done. Also, i can't split table manually as it required code change. Is there any other possibilities to handle huge data?